# How to delete the contents of a directory (files and subdirectory) without deletecting the directory itself with Java NIO?

Tags: java, file, directory, nio

I'm using the following JAVA 8 code to delete a directory and its contents (files, subdirectories and directory). If I want to refactor the code in order to preserve the directory and erase only its content, how can I achieve this?

```java
Path pathToBeDeleted =  Paths.get(directoryPath);
Files.walk(pathToBeDeleted)
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .map(Path::toFile)
    .forEach(File::delete);
```

Comment: Why do you need to sort the elements of the stream? You're only deleting, so you don't need it.

Comment: You may want to use `Files#walkFileTree`. I believe `sorted` will buffer the entire file tree (rooted at `pathToBeDeleted`) in memory, though that may not matter for you.

Comment: @Boris Reversing the order probably ensures files are deleted before directories which avoids a `DirectoryNotEmptyException`, though I'm not positive.

Comment: As @Slaw says I have to sort the elements in order to avoid a DirectoryNotEmptyException exception (Java NIO requires an empty directory in order to delete it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) to your stream (before the map operation):

```java
filter(path -> !path.equals(pathToBeDeleted))
```

This will return a stream consisting of the directory contents only.